# Using Another Native Library in a custom react Native library

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I created a React Native package using `npx create-react-native-library`. I want to add and use a package with native code, such as `react-native-fs`, within this package. I added react-native-fs to the `dependencies` in the `package.json` file. However, when I publish the package and add it to my project, it gives an error stating that it cannot find the react-native-fs package.

`node_modules` folder have `react-native-fs`. I know the problem is because the native code is not being loaded on the iOS side. However, my library's pod is being installed. How can I ensure that it also installs the pods related to react-native-fs?

When I publish my package and try to use it in a different application, the react-native-fs package is added to the node_modules folder. However, the native link processes (pod for iOS and I don't know the name for Android) are not being performed. My package has a .podspec file. Do I need to take any action here? I haven't found a solution yet. Currently, I'm proceeding with peerDependencies, but I need to address this issue.,

Additionally, when I add it as a `dependency` and manually add the pod within the application, it works perfectly. I want to perform this process within the package.

```
pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
```